# Find numeric and character columns that are perfectly correlated / redundant

Tags: r, correlation

I have a data set with several hundred columns.  It contains mailing list data and several of the columns seem to be exact duplicates of each other but in different form.

For instance:

```
rowNum    StateCode       StateName      StateAbbreviation
  1          01             UTAH               UT
  2          01             UTAH               UT
  3          03             TEXAS              TX
  4          03             TEXAS              TX
  5          03             TEXAS              TX
  6          44             OHIO               OH
  7          44             OHIO               OH
  8          44             OHIO               OH
 ...         ...            ...                ...
```

I'd like to remove the overlapping data and just keep the numeric columns if possible so only one column contains the same information.  Thus, the above example would become:

```
rowNum    StateCode
      1          01 
      2          01   
      3          03  
      4          03  
      5          03 
      6          44
      7          44
      8          44 
     ...         ...
```

I've tried using `cor()` but this only works for numeric variables.  I've tried `caret::nearZeroVar()` but this only works with in the column itself.

Does anyone have any suggestions for finding perfectly correlated columns involving non-numeric data?

Thanks.

Comment: Just edited my answer to simplify its approach. It now uses `cor()`, which I should of course have picked up from your question to start with. Thanks for the cool question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a fun and fast solution. It first converts the data.frame to an appropriately structured integer-class matrix, and then uses `cor()` to identify the redundant columns.

```
## Read in the data
df <- read.table(text="rowNum    StateCode       StateName      StateAbbreviation
  1          01             UTAH               UT
  2          01             UTAH               UT
  3          03             TEXAS              TX
  4          03             TEXAS              TX
  5          03             TEXAS              TX
  6          44             OHIO               OH
  7          44             OHIO               OH
  8          44             OHIO               OH", header=TRUE)

## Convert data.frame to a matrix with a convenient structure
## (have a look at m to see where this is headed)
l <- lapply(df, function(X) as.numeric(factor(X, levels=unique(X))))
m <- as.matrix(data.frame(l))

## Identify pairs of perfectly correlated columns    
M <- (cor(m,m)==1)
M[lower.tri(M, diag=TRUE)] <- FALSE

## Extract the names of the redundant columns
colnames(M)[colSums(M)>0]
[1] "StateName"         "StateAbbreviation"
```

Answer (score 3):

Would this do the trick? I'm basing it off the idea that if you call `table(col1, col2)`,
any columns in the table will only have one non-zero value if the columns are duplicates, e.g.:

```
     OHIO TEXAS UTAH
  1     0     0    2
  3     0     3    0
  44    3     0    0
```

So something like this:

```
dup.cols <- read.table(text='rowNum    StateCode       StateName      StateAbbreviation
  1          01             UTAH               UT
  2          01             UTAH               UT
  3          03             TEXAS              TX
  4          03             TEXAS              TX
  5          03             TEXAS              TX
  6          44             OHIO               OH
  7          44             OHIO               OH
  8          44             OHIO               OH', header=T)
library(plyr)
combs <- combn(ncol(dup.cols), 2)
adply(combs, 2, function(x) {
  t <- table(dup.cols[ ,x[1]], dup.cols[ , x[2]])
  if (all(aaply(t1, 2, function(x) {sum(x != 0) == 1}))) {
    paste("Column numbers ", x[1], x[2], "are duplicates")
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should return for you a map telling you which variables match each other.

```
check.dup <- expand.grid(names(dat),names(dat)) #find all variable pairs
check.dup[check.dup$Var1 != check.dup$Var2,] #take out self-reference
check.dup$id <- mapply(function(x,y) {
        x <- as.character(x); y <- as.character(y)
            #if number of levels is different, discard; keep the number for later
        if ((n <- length(unique(dat[,x]))) != length(unique(dat[,y])))  {
            return(FALSE)
            }
            #subset just the variables in question to get pairs
        d <- dat[,c(x,y)]
            #find unique pairs
        d <- unique(d)
            #if number of unique pairs is the number of levels from before,
            #then the pairings are one-to-one
        if( nrow(d) == n ) {
            return(TRUE)
        } else return(FALSE)
    },
    check.dup$Var1,
    check.dup$Var2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dat <- read.table(text="rowNum    StateCode       StateName     
   1          01             UTAH
   2          01             UTAH
   3          03             TEXAS
   4          03             TEXAS 
   5          03             TEXAS 
   6          44             OHIO
   7          44             OHIO
   8          44             OHIO", header=TRUE)

 dat [!duplicated(dat[, 2:3]), ]
#------------
  rowNum StateCode StateName
1      1         1      UTAH
3      3         3     TEXAS
6      6        44      OHIO
```

Comment: The question was asking about duplicate columns, not rows.

Comment: @Marius: If you are the source of the -1 vote, let me ask you if you think it reasonable to downvote an answer _after_ the OP has changed the question to be something else than what it started out?  When I posted this answer there was no "StateAbbreviation"  column and there was no "correct answer" example in the question. I'm not worried about my points total but I think it's poor citizenship to downvote when the questions are changing.

Comment: I agree -- a downvote here serves no useful purpose, and just makes SO a less friendly place.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was an answer based on a skim read of the question ("find duplicates!"). I didn't realize it was posted pre-edit.